# View and ViewModel Connection

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

I have two files (a View and a ViewModel), but I can't figure out how to get the view to read the information stored in the model and display it.  I have looked at a few related questions on this site, but haven't found anything that I have been able to get to work yet. That might just be because I don't fully understand the solutions that have been given, but I was hoping that posting this would allow someone to elaborate on a solution directly related to the project I am working on.

View File:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sponsors";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
</hgroup>

<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th></th><th>Sponsor</th><th>Description</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: sponsor">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><select data-bind="text: cName"></select></td>
            <td><select data-bind="text: sDescribe"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ViewModel File:

```
    ko.applyBindings({
sponsor: [
        self.companyNames = [
            { cName: "company1", sDescribe: "company 1 been nice enough to support my bowling career by paying for a couple of my tournaments." },
            { cName: "company2", sDescribe: "I am an employee at company 2 and it is where I purchase all of my equipment. The owner has also been nice enough to supply me with a few shirts to wear in tournaments and I have even received a few bowling balls from him." }
        ]);
```

I have just recently begun to work with MVC frameworks so I am still learning. I've been using online tutorials to get to where I am now. This view is the 3rd one that I have worked on and is so far the only one that I cannot get to display. The others do not use a javascript page though to display their info because none of their info is dynamically loaded.

Comment: Are you making sure to add a reference to your view model file?  It has to be included on the view page in some way or another

Comment: well the view model file looks to be a javascript file, so I just meant the view html file has to know about.  ``<script type='text/javascript' src='myViewModel.js'/>``...looks like you got your issue figured out though.

Comment: The solution below worked with the javascript being added on the same page as the html. After I read your comment, I moved the function back over to the .js file and added the reference at the top of the html file for it. Now it all works the way I originally wanted it to. It just took a combination of your suggestion and the answer posted by tabalin. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view model should be valid JS object. 
Like following

```
var viewModel = {
    sponsor: [
        { cName: "company1", sDescribe: "company 1 been nice enough to support my bowling career by paying for a couple of my tournaments." },
        { cName: "company2", sDescribe: "I am an employee at company 2 and it is where I purchase all of my equipment. The owner has also been nice enough to supply me with a few shirts to wear in tournaments and I have even received a few bowling balls from him." }
    ]
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/GHjRL/

Comment: Ok. I changed my viewmodel file to match what you have typed here. but I keep getting the same thing when I try to load the web page. The Table Headers come up "Sponsor" and "Description" but the only thing that shows up below them are empty drop down menus. I'm not even sure where the drop down menus are coming from.

Comment: I actually realized my mistake. I had used the wrong html entity in the table. When I did the tutorial, I was editing it to fit my data and the tutorial used drop down menus (where I just wanted to display information), but once I figured that out your solution worked for displaying the data. Thanks!